# Week based event pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got my source table in the form of:

```
event   start   end
event1  21/01/2019  15/02/2019
event2  01/01/2019  08/01/2019
event3  15/01/2019  13/02/2019
event4  07/01/2019  18/03/2019
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a weekly summary of events that were happening at each particular week of the year. Like so:

```
week    events
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
...
```

As I'm completely clueless, any hint as of how to do that is much appreciated.
I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: This gets potentially complicated, because the definition/numbering of a week usually varies from year to year, depending on which standard you use.  Could you ever have more than one year of data?

Comment: No, my interest is within one year time frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to make use of window functions as follows:

```
select distinct w1.weeknum, 
    count(e1.id) over(partition by w1.weeknum) as eventqty
from (select generate_series(1, 52, 1) AS weeknum) w1
left join eventlog e1
on extract(week from startdate)<=w1.weeknum and extract(week from enddate)>=w1.weeknum
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ese8nuc9DSDPft6pj9VSR7/0) is the working example.

Comment: Looks like it solves the issue perfectly! Is there a way to keep track of year as well (just in case I need more than 1 year frame)?

Answer (score 0):

First, I caution you from leaving the year out of the calculation.  Such date ranges typically go over year boundaries so you need to be careful.

I think the most efficient way to do such a calculation is to counts "ins" and "outs" from the dates.  This involves splitting the data and then re-aggregating.

The query looks like:

```
with el as (
      select id,
             date_trunc('week', startdate) as wk,
             1 as inc
      from eventlog
      union all
      select id,
             date_trunc('week', enddate) + interval '1 week' as wk,
             -1 as inc
      from eventlog
     )
select wk,
       sum(inc) as week_net,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by wk) as active_in_week
from el
group by wk
order by wk;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ese8nuc9DSDPft6pj9VSR7/0) is a dbfiddle.